# yasnippet: how to expand a snippet from a string and have the fields recognized?

Tags: yasnippet

**Q:** how do I get `yasnippet` to expand a text string correctly (recognizing snippet fields) from inside elisp code?

A very simple snippet is a just a string of characters with some control characters intermingled.  We can also use elisp forms to create richer snippets, but it's not clear to me how to expand them appropriately.

Here's a simple example that captures the problem.  I'm creating an `org-mode` snippet to insert a link skeleton, which looks like `[[source][description]]`.  The following simple snippet produces the desired behavior of "start in the source field, end up in the description field":

```
[[$1][$0]]
```

We can intermingle elisp code in snippets (wrapped in `s).  I would have thought that the following would produce exactly the same behavior as the simpler version, because the `if` will simply evaluate to `[[$1][$0]]` as a string:

```
`(if t "[[$1][$0]]")`
```

It does not do so, however.  Instead, it acts as if the `$0` and `$1` fields are not fields, ends the snippet, and places point after the final `]`.  So: how does one get the desired behavior when an elisp form evaluates to a text string with `yasnippet` fields embedded in that string?

**EDIT:** as requested, here's the particular use-case that inspired the question.  If the X clipboard contains a url link, I'd like it to populate the source field in the org link ([[*source*][description]]) and leave me in the destination field.  It uses a helper function (`dan-xclipboard-link-p`) which returns the url if it exists, or else `nil`.  It seems to me that I should be able to do something like this:

```
`(let ((link (dan-xclipboard-link-p)))
   (if link
       (concat "[[" link "][$0]]")
     "[[$1][$0]]"))`
```

In fact, with an earlier version of yasnippet, a version of this code worked as I intended it.

**EDIT 2:** Interestingly enough, this snippet works when there is a link on the X clipboard, but fails when not (ie, it doesn't recognize `$1` as a field:

```
[[`(or (dan-xclipboard-link-p) "$1")`][$0]]
```

Comment: How about `(if t (yas-insert-snippet))`? Can you give a more realistic conditional so that we can understand the actual use case ? This could be a [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) with more elegant solutions.

Comment: I'm not seeing how `yas-insert-snippet` applies here.  At any rate, an actual use case (that used to work) is now in the question.

Comment: @Dan It does not work because the elisp form is evaluated when the is **being expanded**, at which point yasnippet has already read the snippet. I guess what you want to do is templatize the template itself, not sure that is possible with yasnippet at this point of time

Comment: @IqbalAnsari I have kind of crude way of templatizing the snippets themselves. See my longer solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### **SHORT SOLUTION**

If you do not mind an additional `TAB` keystroke, definining your snippet as below should work.

```
 [[${1:`(dan-xclipboard-link-p)`}][$0]]
```

The embedded lisp returns the url from the clipboard if it exists and sets it to be the default text in the field `$1`. You can type over the link to change it or just `TAB (yas-next-field)` to move point to `$0`.

### **LONGER FULL FEATURED SOLUTION**

I got the idea based on @IqbalAnsari's comment after writing the shorter solution.
You can use the condition predicate for choosing which snippet to expand. For instance define two snippets with the same trigger

**SNIPPET 1**

```
  # -*- mode: snippet; require-final-newline: nil -*-
  # name: org-link
  # key: [[
  # binding: direct-keybinding
  # type: snippet
  # condition: (not (dan-xclipboard-link-p))
  # --
  [[$1][$0]]
```

**SNIPPET 2**

```
  # -*- mode: snippet; require-final-newline: nil -*-
  # name: org-link-with-default-paste
  # key: [[
  # binding: direct-keybinding
  # type: snippet
  # condition: (dan-xclipboard-link-p)
  # --
  [[`(dan-xclipboard-link-p)`][$0]]
```

Both the snippets have the same trigger, but have inverted predicates denoted by the `condition:`. As such only one of the snippets will be expanded depending upon the value returned by `(dan-xclipboard-link-p)`. This way you can position the point at `$0` directly.

To answer the general question, no it is not possible for yasnippet to recognize fields within elisp as it parses embedded elisp blocks separately without any concern for normal template syntax. I am not sure how the previous versions worked though.

Comment: Great, I was thinking of something along the same lines. Though I would have preferred the extra 'tab' over writing two snippets. +1

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts.  By the way, I'd come up with something similar to the short solution and fixed a typo with the brackets for future reference.  The conditional snippets are a nice touch.